# How To fix Component Error on lightning RecordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created an aura component by I keep getting an Error:
**Action failed: lightning: recordviewForm$controller$controller$handleRecordIdChange [Cannot read property 'getList' of null]**

[image]

How can i fix this error?
Thanks,

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

<!--<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>-->
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" description="The record object to be displayed"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object" description="A simplified view record object to be displayed"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="record" layoutType="FULL"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    targetError="{!v.recordError}"
    targetRecord="{!v.record}"
    targetFields ="{!v.simpleRecord}"
    mode="VIEW"/>

 <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.simpleRecord.AccountId}" objectApiName="Account">
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Tip_To_Smarties__c" class="custom-color"/>
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Customer_Technical_ID_Card_Link__c" class="custom-color"/>            
    </div>
</lightning:recordViewForm>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record View Form Documentation:
[image: Record View Form]

Can you wrap `lightning:recordViewForm` inside an `aura:if` to make sure we have the `v.simpleRecord.AccountId` value populated from `force:recordData`

We don't have record id available on load and we are trying to view the record without recordId which is required.

So just wrap the `lightning:recordViewForm` inside an `aura:if`

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!!empty(v.simpleRecord.AccountId)}">
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.simpleRecord.AccountId}" objectApiName="Account">
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Tip_To_Smarties__c" class="custom-color"/>
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Customer_Technical_ID_Card_Link__c" class="custom-color"/>            
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you directly pass recordId to the lightning record edit form like below. I think the recordId is not populated on page load to lightning recordEditForm.For me the below code worked. `<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Account">`